# Need help reversing formula x = z / (1 / (z / distance))

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’m trying to find a way to reverse the following formula:

```
x = z / (1 / (z / distance))
```

So that if given x and distance as input it results in z

My math skills aren’t the best, and I’m wondering if it is even possible. I tried lots of things (including chatGPT) but nothing that produces the correct results.

Comment: \begin{align}
1 / (z / distance) &= distance / z \\
z / (distance / z) &= z * z / distance
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
1 / (z / distance) &= distance / z \\
z / (distance / z) &= z * z / distance \\
\end{align}
so you have :
$ x = z^2 / distance $
and therefore : $ z = \sqrt{x \times distance} $
(if I'm not mistaken...)

The general rule is that "to divide by something, you multiply by its inverse".